# OPT301 Photodiode Output Measurement

Tags: adc, photodiode, high-impedance

I am working on a setup where  [OPT301](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opt301.pdf) is fed with an optically filtered light output yield a very low current which is then Current to Voltage converted by integrated op-amp within the device, but the feedback resistance used here is 100 Mega Ohm to derive output voltage of 0.14 V (min) to 1.2 V (max).

Now, I wish to digitize this voltage for the purpose of monitoring it over a period of time. For this I tried to buffer the output from sensor, amplify (using difference amplifier configuration) it to range of 0V-5V and then feed it to [MCP3208](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21298c.pdf) ADC through an op-amp buffer again. Op-amp that I am using is [TL084](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl082.pdf) which is a JFET-Input Op-Amp.

Now at the input of all the devices put in this circuit I am able to measure constant voltage for a particular sensor output, but as soon as I try to retrieve my ADC output through SPI (with as low as 10KHz SPI clock), I see an oscillating voltage on the logger. However, the multimeter gives a static reading all the while.

Following is my circuit:

[image]

Please suggest where I am going wrong.

1. Is the choice of Op-amp is wrong? [Will be trying the same logic with OP07]
2. Is there a need to filter the sensor first?

Comment: What is the frequency of the oscillation you are seeing? Could be that your multimeter is too slow to show it. If your circuit diagram is complete, a problem might be missing decoupling caps. Sometimes small capacitance is needed to get an OP circuit stable - but I'm not analog enough to provide you with a good answer on that.

Comment: Oscillation at what frequency?  Could it be fluorescent or LED lighting detected by your sensor?

Comment: Use an oscilloscope , the multimeter makes an average over hundreds of milliseconds. Most likely the light is the source of noise, filter or make an average over many ADC readings.

Comment: Did you provide power supply bypass capacitors for any of your ICs? Did you bild this on a PCB or breadboard?

Comment: Do your VEE, +15, and +5 V sources share a common ground? What voltage is VEE?

Comment: Also, your sensor has an integrated amplifier which requires power supplies. Did the power supplies for the sensor share ground with the circuit you showed? How long are the wires (signal and power) connecting the sensor to the buffer/ADC circuit?

Comment: @The Photon. I am using a standard linear power supply for +/- 15V, 5V. Vee=-15V. I have assembled the circuit on a general purpose PCB with all signal and supply grounds being common. The sensor output is taken in the form of two wire of which ground is connected to circuit ground (nothing else is taken from photodiode pcb which is housed in a closed box). Yes, cables are pretty long stretching into atleast 5m.

Comment: Moreover, I have tried using an input of the same scale from an external power supply instead of photodiode output, and I get a proper, equivalent digital reading and no such oscillation. For frequency of oscillation, I will share the DSO output which also showed some oscillatory behavior.

Comment: Can you include a schematic showing how you hooked up the OPT301? It needs more connections than just signal and ground.

Comment: An update. I found that CRO showed a disturbed yet a 50 Hz signal (having other frequency components as well). So, I did connect the DC ground of circuit with the body of the OPT301 IC mounting case and this way 50 Hz AC was gone but still I can see an approx 10 Hz signal making the reading out of ADC to still fluctuate (but approximately by 10-20 mV) that too after applying averaging of over 100 samples per reading. Should I try implementing a filter in digital domain?